# Cannot compile javascript using d3 to typescript on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to convert an existing web page which uses JavaScript and d3 to work with Typescript using Visual Studio 2017 as an IDE. The first problem I encountered was that VS 2017 no longer supports "HTML application built with Typescript" - so I built one in VS 2015 and copied it across. All I really wanted was an empty environment into which I could add my form and my JavaScript code. Having got this far, I discovered that I needed to import a typings file for d3, so I added that, so my resulting code looked like this:

[image]

I found that I was still getting the following errors:

[image]

- saying that I was missing --allowJs. After a bit of searching it appeared that I could resolve the problem by setting up a file called tsconfig.json in my top project folder. I set it up as follows:

  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "allowJs": true
  }
- but I am still getting the same error. Now I am stuck! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using npm?

Comment: No, I really want to just use Visual Studio.

Comment: No that is not what I meant, so it means you don't.  What is the folder structure?

Comment: This is the message: Error TS6143 Module '../d3/d3.js' was resolved to 'C:/Users/Sutherland/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/msIntensity/msIntensity/d3/d3.js', but '--allowJs' is not set. msIntensity C:\Users\Sutherland\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\msIntensity\msIntensity\ts\msIntensity.ts 6 Active

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: There is an outer folder called msIntensity, which contains the msIntensity.sln file and an inner folder which contains the tsconfig file. I have put the msIntensity.ts file in a folder called ts one level down from this. It is this file which is failing to compile.

Comment: Is the resolved path correct? What d3 version are you using? Older versions don't export anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139679/discussion-between-david-carrick-sutherland-and-dummy).